# Issues implementing Angular Dynamic Components - AOT & Change Detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-aot, angular-dynamic-components

I am trying to implement an Angular library which will encapsulate the logic required to add dynamic components to the DOM. Applications that consume this library must be allowed to provide a list of Components that will be dynamic, and then define "outlets" where these dynamic components must be inserted at runtime.

My code is heavily inspired by two articles:

- The first from Max Koretskyi: https://indepth.dev/posts/1054/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular
- The second by Wes Grimes: https://itnext.io/building-an-aot-friendly-dynamic-content-outlet-in-angular-c2790195cb94

The basic structure of my code is as below:

- A library `ng-dynamic-components` with a module `NgDynamicComponentsModule`, which allows the consumer to define a list of components that should be available for adding to the DOM at runtime
- A service , which maintains the registry of such dynamic components, and their component factories, to be used to instantiate the component when needed
- An outlet component which handles the logic of actually placing the dynamic component into the DOM using a `ViewContainerRef`
- A `dynamic-test-app` that imports this library and consumes it with some test components that are dynamically injected -- `OneComponent`, `TwoComponent`, and `ThreeComponent`

My code is available at: https://github.com/kiranjholla/ng-dynamic-components. To run my code, just clone this Git repository and then type in `npm install` and `npm start`. This will first build the library using the option `--prod`, and then build the test application using the options `--prod --aot=false --buildOptimizer=false`, and then start a `http-server` instance to serve the `dist` folder

**Now my questions: the above code works only when the application is built with `--aot=false --buildOtimizer=false`; when AOT is enabled, I get an error stating that the compiler is unavailable.**
[image]

**But, I have already provided the Compiler specifically using the `JitCompilerFactory`. How can I get it to work with AOT??**

Any help/pointers, greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Angular version are you using? I think both linked articles are pre-Ivy. I wouldn’t expect aot to work (as you are specifically  wanting JIT)..

Comment: Yes, this is Angular 11. Which means it is Ivy.

However, there must be a way to cater to such a use-case in Ivy too? I understand that the syntax to be used might change.

Also, any clues on why Change Detection won't run after adding the components into the view?

Comment: so where and why do you use the compiler?

Comment: I have a test application `dynamic-test-app` which consumes the dynamic components library: [`NgDynamicComponentsModule.withRegistry()`](https://github.com/kiranjholla/ng-dynamic-components/blob/main/projects/dynamic-test-app/src/app/app.module.ts#L15).

A module with all dynamic components is passed into the `withRegistry` call. The `NgDynamicComponentsModule` has a service [`ComponentRegistryService`](https://github.com/kiranjholla/ng-dynamic-components/blob/main/projects/ng-dynamic-components/src/lib/services/component-registry.service.ts) which compiles the dynamic components at runtime.

Comment: The idea is to provide this library `NgDynamicComponentsModule` which can taken any Component Registry and handle the dynamic instantiation and rendering of those components.

We have a use-case where we need to determine the component to be rendered at run-time based on some data coming in from the server.

Comment: @Kiran, what if you pre-compile all components at build time and later load component factories for rendering that are need based on the server information?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi Thanks for that suggestion! I am going to try that.